# How to output json in spring mvc

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, schema

I am using Spring boot with mvc. I have a json schema for request and response. Basically the user posts data (in json) to a url, the controller does its logic and returns a json. I am having difficulty in returning the json. So far, I have a couple of views (in thymeleaf) with hardcoded responses which I dont want. I just want to use an object which I can edit and send back to the client. The response is very simple. This is the schema of the response:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"message":{
"minLength":1,
"type":"string"

}
},
"required": [
"message"
]
}
```

I have an object of type response which conforms to my response json schema. I basically want to output this object to the client. But not sure how as my controller returns a String and this string is usually the name of the html page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to your controller method and it will use the returned value as a response rather than as a path to a page.

If you want that all methods of your controller return direct data (and not page paths), you can annotate your controller with `@RestController` rather than `@Controller`.

Comment: I've added the @RestController and it worked. Learnt something new.